# Docker-Compose Error on CentOS 7: Shared Library Mapping Issue

Tags: linux, docker-compose, tmp

I've encountered an issue with Docker on CentOS 7. Although I have successfully installed both Docker and Docker-Compose, when I run docker-compose --version, I receive the following error:

```
docker-compose: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object
```

After some investigation, I suspect this might be related to the noexec option set on my /tmp directory (Docker-compose needs to load some shared libraries from /tmp). Here's the relevant output from cat /etc/fstab:

```
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,noexec             0 0
/root/images/tmpfile.bin   /tmp   ext4    rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev    0 0
/tmp /var/tmp none rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,bind 0 0
```

I need advice on how to resolve this. Should I modify the fstab settings for the /tmp directory, or is there another solution? Thank you for your help!

I am using CENTOS7

I have another server which have this out for cat etc/fstab

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root /                       xfs     defaults        1 1
UUID=6fd8c651-0add-48e8-a83d-454eb2241b26 /boot                   xfs     defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/centos-home /home                   xfs     defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/centos-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

On this server docker-compose --version worked fine

Comment: CentOS 7 is based on 10 year old technology and will [reach End of Support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS#End-of-support_schedule) in  6 months. You probably shouldn't do any new development on your existing CentOS 7 server.  -|- Note that most Linux applications wil honour the `TMPDIR`  environment variable and you can also use that instruct `docker` and `docker-compose` to use a different directory for temporary storage, i.e. use your existing `/var/tmp/` or make a new directory  `mkdir -p /data/tmp` ; `export TMPDIR=/data/tmp ` and then run your Docker commands.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and reply @HBruijn. export TMPDIR=/data/tmp Is this for current session only or will it be permanent?

Comment: Environment variables set on the command line exist only for the lifetime of that session (simplified until you log out) You make an environment persistent  by ensuring that it gets set whenever you need  it (for example by setting it in a ~/.bashrc , including it in a systemd service unit, adjusting a start-up script etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying info. Can I use this command If I want to specifically define tmp directory for docker-compose command only in bashrc ? alias docker-compose="TMPDIR=${HOME}/tmp docker-compose"

Comment: Yes. Just try if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Hbruijn comments. I tried following and now docker-compose is working now.

Created new directory for docker-compose tmp files.

Then set this in ~/.bash_profile.

```
alias docker-compose="TMPDIR=/var/var/tmp docker-compose"
```

Now all related docker-compose commands are working as expected.